# Kendo grid button click arguments

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with a button column. When the button is clicked, I want it to call a javascript function with the row's data as parameters. Here's what I have so far

```js
$(grd).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    detailInit: detailInit,
    columns: [ {field: "foo", title: "bar" },
               {field: "Y" },
               {command: { text: "MyButton", click: doStuff } } ]
    });

function doStuff(e)
{
    //e is click events but I want to pass in data from the row instead
    //following is code I found here but item is null for me
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var item = $(grd).data("kendoGrid").dataItem(row);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the data pertaining to the row which the button was clicked.

```
function doStuff(e) {

    var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");    // get the current table row (tr)
    var item = this.dataItem(tr);          // get the date of this row

    alert(item.PropertyName);
}
```

Comment: okay, maybe I was using the wrong code? I'm not selecting a row, just clicking the button in the column. Currently, this is what I see in console.log for tr: [prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: undefined, jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, selector: ""…]context: undefinedlength: 0prevObject: n.fn.init[1]0: T.extend.initlength: 1__proto__: n[0]__proto__: n[0]

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify better. This code block will work.